# GCP workflows Memory limits exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to use Google Cloud Workflows to perform SQL queries on a BigQuery dataset.
my pipeline would perform several consecutive queries that are mainly in the form of :

```
create or replace table project_x.dataset_y.table_z as 
     select * from project_x.dataset_y.view_z
```

where the view of query n is reading the resulting table of query n-1.
To solve the issue of this dependency I'm using the code at the end of this question. The issue is my workflow returns the error even with one query:

```
{"message":"ResourceLimitError: Memory usage limit exceeded","tags":["ResourceLimitError"]}
```

on the console, the query takes less than 1 minute to complete.
Any ideas how is my workflow is using more memory than it should? and what's the best to fix it?

workflow code:

```
main:
  steps:
    - initialize:
        assign:
          - project: "project_x"
          - dataset: "dataset_y"
    - query_n:
        call: BQJobsQuery
        args:
          project: ${project}
          sqlQuery: ${"Create or Replace table `dataset_y.table_z`
                          as select * from `dataset_y.view_z`;"}
        result: bq_response
    - get_job_status:
        call: getJobFinalStatus
        args:
          project: ${project}
          job_id: ${bq_response.jobReference.jobId}
        result: job_status_response

    - returned_result:
        return: ${job_status_response}

BQJobsQuery:
  params: [project, sqlQuery]
  steps:
    - runQuery:
        try:
          call: http.post
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/queries"}
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
            body:
              useLegacySql: false
              query: ${sqlQuery}
          result: queryResult
        except:
          as: e
          steps:
            - UnhandledException:
                raise: ${e}
    - queryCompleted:
        return: ${queryResult.body}

getJobFinalStatus:
    params: [project, job_id]
    steps:
      - sleep:
          call: sys.sleep
          args:
            seconds: 5
      - getJobCurrentStatus:
          call: http.get
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/jobs/"+job_id}
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
          result: jobStatusRes
      - isJobFinished:
          switch:
            - condition: ${jobStatusRes.body.status.state == "RUNNING"}
              next: sleep
      - jobFinished:
          return: ${jobStatusRes.body}
```

Comment: The memory limit has been raised since this was posted, including the removal of an encoding overhead that often reduced the size of maps (objects) that could be stored. The techniques mentioned by uri-kastir below are also helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The total size for the [variables is limited to 512 KB](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/quotas#resource_limits). I don't know the length of the BigQuery queries response, but I suppose you break this limit.

There is already an open public issue to increase the memory limit of variables on GCP Workflows. You can follow its progress on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/183100019). It should be released soon! Stay tuned!

Comment: The memory limit is now 256KB, and no longer includes encoding overhead that previously reduced the size of maps that could be stored.

Comment: It looks like the limit for variables and arguments is now 512 KB: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/quotas#resource_limits

Answer (score 3):

Please note the every time you assign a value into a "result", it is added to the total size of the variables so if you do not need the result down the road, you can omit it.
Also, you can assign null to the variable that are no longer needed, this frees its space for other variables.